# Getting CompanyID in Sap B1 web client extension that is not a URL mashup

Tags: sapb1

I'm in the process of writing an extension that can link to my web functionality. My web app is a C# net6.0 application that establishes it's own connection to Service Layer and DI etc, it is hosted externally to the SAP Hana server.

It looks as though Sap supplied an injectable variable in their mta.yaml file for URL mashups - if my aplications url were fixed, I'd be able to build a URL mashup extension using:

```
   path: https://myfixedaddress.com/?companyID={b1-companyID}
```

Unfortunately my application need to be installed onto an on-premise Windows server. Both the server name/DNS name and/or the port number could be variable. I can't add the companyID token to the mta path anymore, because that causes the mta build tool to report that the path cannot be found. I also can't seem to add custom parameters to work with the ExtensionManager.

At the moment, I have a solution that in an ideal world I wouldn't want to use, I could basically add a UDT and store A) The path of my extension, and B) The Database name of the company database. (A) may be unavoidable, but (B) seems a bit odd to have to put the name of the database in the database.

Does anybody know whether it's possible to create web client extensions that use parameters in Extension Manager?

Does anybody know how it may be possible for a web client extension (React) to determine which company database the web client is running against? Is there a service layer method that tells us? or is there a way to get the MTA path variable to include the {b1-companyID} token even when using 'mta build' command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in to control center you can check network requests to SAP SLD server so you know how SLD is getting it, then you can use same request to obtain information you need.

Comment: I do notice that SAP Web Client calls into various APIs, but generally, if I can't find the SDK documentation for an API that the Vendor uses, I don't use it because hidden/internal interfaces are subject to change.

Comment: Totally agree with you, but as long as it's for reading data I compromised with this becuase there was no better option for me.